# JQuery collapsible panels working together

Tags: jquery

I have this simple question about collapsible panels with JQuery. I have a left side panel(top to bottom) with a menu and a bottom panel with that contains form elements.
The left and bottom panels are both collapsibe and must not overlap.
The thing is that when i collapse the left panel the bottom panel should expand to the full width and vice versa.

Can anyone point me to any example for this, please? I couldn´t find one.
Thanks

Comment: knock knock....where is the brilliant sample code you have tried so far ??

Comment: Can you make a fiddle so that we can get a clear idea on your concept?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your question is not so clear and the concept is blurry. But to achieve your requirement, you should use jQuery UI and the animation should be `accordian()`. This can also be achieved by a combination of `slideUp()` & `slideDown()` functions.

Below is a sample click event on a div element where I use toggle & slideUp().

```
//click function for expanding event 
$(document).on('click',".bill-description",function()
{
    //close all elements other than the clicked one 
    $("element list").not($(this).next("clicked element")).slideUp(600);
    //open the clicked element
    $(this).next("clicked element").slideToggle(600);

});
```

The above function is written for a custom accordion effect. To know accordion effect read [this.](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)

The first line is used to close all the elements that is not the one clicked. Hence the `not`.
Then the second is used to open the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some accordion / collapse plugin (ie: jQueryUI) ?

If you just want to use jQuery this can be done using `.show()`, `.hide()` and/or `.toggle()`..

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#panel1,#panel2').toggle();
})
```

[**Demo**](http://bootply.com/60764)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the straight answer. It´s just like the site where you put the demo, but the left panel goes all the way to the bottom and the bottom panel should adjust to the left panel width

Comment: Yeah, you made need to play with the demo to get it the way you want. It's meant to demonstrate 2 collapsing panels.